# Do I need to remove views from superviews in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

If I alloc/init a view and add it to a another view in code (I did not use a xib) - do I need to remove it when the containing UIViewController's dealloc message is sent? I have seen this code in certain places, and wondered is it necessary under some circumstances to free memory?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: If this is a new project you should consider using ARC anyway. Otherwise answers below are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this,

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:v];
[v release];
```

or

```
UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:v];
```

,the `v` will be released when its parent view release;

When the parent view use `addSubview`, it  will retain the subview, and will release the subview when it is released.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessary. All `UIView` subclasses hold `subviews` array, which gets released in the final `UIView` dealloc message, which releases your views.